# An unkwon option in flash

Tags: flash, jquery-animate

I noticed that when you select a text in animate 2021, a session called option - where you can put a link- is shown in panel property/object, but I do not know exactly how to use this, could someone explain me, or send me a tutorial?

I tried to search about it but did not find.